# I cannot access this Stack Overflow question

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I am trying to access this link: [How to redirect to the referrer in a filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035060/how-to-redirect-to-the-referrer-in-a-filter)

I got HTTP 200 response with an empty page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
        <title>how-to-redirect-to-the-referrer-in-a-filter (1×1)</title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px;">
        <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035060/how-to-redirect-to-the-referrer-in-a-filter">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's just you :)

Comment: I've tried different browsers, but no luck. It's only this question.

Comment: No doctype? My eyes hurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that it is Kaspersky's fault. I turned it off and it worked. I still wonder what this page contains that Kaspersky needs to block it.

Comment: Try turning it back on and hitting the URL with HTTPS instead.  I doubt that it'd trip anything up after that.  It might be Kaspersky scanning the webpage and believing that something is awry when it really isn't.

Comment: I did turn it back, and it is still blocking me from accessing that page. I tried to access it with `https://`, but that didn't help. I bet the Kaspersky browser plugin is the one which scanning the page, not the firewall.

Comment: Sounds like Kaspersky has the ability to read your encrypted communications.  I'm not sold on its viability.  In either event...I'm at least satisfied to hear that turning it off does allow you to view the question.

Comment: @Makoto Kaspersky installs a root certificated on the system. Chrome doesn't like it for communications with Google servers.

Comment: @Braiam:  I wouldn't either.  Kaspersky performs a consensual MITM in the name of security.  Spooky.

Comment: @Makoto well, since malaware is using encryption to bluff AV software, we can't have nice things

Comment: AV software **is** malware